HttpError 403: Quota Exceeded for YouTube Data API v3 CommentThreads Request
I'm encountering an issue when trying to retrieve comments from a YouTube video using the YouTube Data API v3. The error I'm getting is:

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&videoId=tBPBfBdpMDc&pageToken=Z2V0X25ld2VzdF9maXJzdC0tQ2dnSWdBUVZGN2ZST0JJRkNJY2dHQUFTQlFpZElCZ0JFZ1VJaVNBWUFCSUZDSWdnR0FBU0JRaW9JQmdBR0FBaURnb01DT3U2ckxJR0VQQ044ZGdC&textFormat=plainText&key=AIzaSyDzP6VRavAsSJ3HrKwUj9CQaQOOlZAb7zk&alt=json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.', 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]

Is there any way to increase my quota, or are there best practices to manage and reduce API usage effectively? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota
